# ngrx actions are not dispatching when using angular element

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an Angular component that incorporates NgRx for state management and effects. When I use this component within an Angular application, the NgRx effects are functioning correctly. However, when I wrap this component as an Angular element for use in a non-Angular application, the effects do not appear to receive the actions. I have confirmed that I've registered the effects in the module. Is it possible that Angular elements do not work seamlessly with NgRx, particularly when used in a non-Angular context?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, so community can take a look how you developed your component. Also from my personal experience I can say that the approach you took (angular-based web component in a non-angular app) definitely works, so the problem is not in NgRx or Angular.